# bash script not capturing stdout, just stderr

Tags: bash

I have the following script (let's call it move_site.sh) that copies a website directory structure to another server

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/$1 http@$2:/local/htdocs 1>$1$2.out 2>&1
```

So calling it from the command line, I pass it the webiste site directory name, and destination server as such:

```
nohup ./move_site.sh site1 server1 &
```

However, in the resulting that is named site1server1.out, there are only stderr messages, if any.

Can someone tell me how I can get the file and directory names that are copied, included in the output file, so that I have some kind of record?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick try :
Maybe it is because when everything went fine, `scp` doesn't print anything to stdout (?).

Have a try : run your scp command outside the script, most probably you don't have anything on std out. (redirect nothing to $1$2.out, it's still nothing :))

I don't think it is possible with scp but with rsync you can track what has been transferred to stdout. So changing `scp -r` by `rsync -r -v -e` should does the trick. (at least if you can go for rsync unstead of scp).